# Using between "template" and function declaration: template<typename trait> using tr = base_trait<trait> void fn(tr::type arg) { ... }

Tags: c++, templates

Is it somehow possible to have a using alias between `template` keyword and function declaration (and possibly object declaration etc.)?

```
template<typename trait> 
using tr = base_trait<trait> 

void fn(tr::type arg) { // edit: typename has to be here?

}
```

If not, how do I achieve this level of readability?

Variants I've come up with aren't perfect:

```
template<typename trait>
struct base_trait : trait {
    using thetype = typename trait::thetype;
};


struct int_trait {
    using thetype = int;
};


/* the pretty version which doesn't compile */
template <typename trait>
using tr = base_trait<trait>. 

void fn(tr::thetype arg) {
    // tr::

}

fn<int_trait>(1);


/* ugly long arglist version which works */
template <typename trait>
void fn(typename base_trait<trait>::thetype arg1, typename base_trait<trait>::thetype arg2) {
    using tr = base_trait<trait>; 

    // tr:: 
}

fn<int_trait>(1);


/* another boilerplate version that still requires `typename` */
template <typename tr>
void fn(typename tr::thetype arg) {
    // typename tr::  

    // wait, I have to type and read typename everywhere... (unless I add `using boilerplateusing = tr; edit: this using should not help?)
}

template <typename trait>
using boilerplateusing = fn<base_trait<trait>>;

boilerplateusing<int_trait>(1);
```

Comment: Any time you would use `tr` you would need to provide a template argument. There is no `tr` type from which to get `tr::thetype`. It's an alias for a template.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I see, so you're saying that I have to use `typename` in all possible ways?

Comment: Not at all. I'm saying that `tr` can't be used as a type without a template argument.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Oh, you refer to the first two lines of code. I didn't want to create a templated alias. I wanted to have an alias that would work even for function parameters. It should be a function template, not a templated alias.

Answer (score 2):

Just add another template parameter that is defaulted with the trait's `type` member like

```
template<typename trait, typename arg_t = typename base_trait<trait>::thetype> 
void fn(arg_t arg) {

}
```

or if you want to keep the trait type you can use

```
template<typename trait, typename tr = base_trait<trait>> 
void fn(typename tr::thetype arg) {

}
```

or you could get have both with

```
template<typename trait, 
         typename tr = base_trait<trait>,
         typename arg_t = typename tr::thetype> 
void fn(arg_t arg) {

}
```

Comment: So essentially I need to use typename (I want to keep the trait type), even if my "prettiest" "between" alias worked, because `tr::thetype` is still a dependent name.

Comment: @Adam Yes, you need the `typename` in the parameter because `thetype` is a depdant name.  I've just updated the answer to show you how you could have both access to the trait and to `thetype` of the trait so you don't need to use `typename` in the parameter.

Comment: Given the comment above, it's so far the shortest working, quite readable. On the other hand, this allows users of `fn` template to pass bullshit which I quite wanted to avoid by having such a base_trait at the first place. After all, it's a parameter and a parameter should be sometimes specified. 

The good thing is that you can put it at the end of the template params and don't care for it, even if variadic params precede it, right? (for function templates only)

Comment: I don't have the experience here. Is this something that would be tolerated in real world, considered a good hack, or an ugly hack that shouldn't be used?

Comment: @Adam You're not going to be able to stop them from passing BS.  Even if your asked for way worked they could still pass BS to the function.  If they do pass BS then they will either get a compiler error or unexpected behavior.  Either way that really isn't your problem.  As far as style goes, I wouldn't say it's bad.